# A condition for a matrix to be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n,\ k$ be two positive integers such that $n \ge 2$ and $1 \le k \le n-1$. If the matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ has exactly $k$ null minors of order $n-1$, then $\det A \neq 0$.

*source: Romanian Mathematical Olympiad, final round , 2012*

Comment: What do you mean by minor?

Comment: And what is a "null minor"? Minor I know, and even principal or chief minor, but null minor I never heard of.

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand the assumption as: among all $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrices, exactly $k$ have zero determinant.

Comment: @Don Antonio: Leonid Kovalev is right. I`m sorry for my enghlish. I`ve searched in the dictionary and "null" means equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the olympiad is over and it's legitimate for us to discuss this problem. Anyway, I hide the answer as to not spoil the fun.

> Let's use the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). We know that exactly $k$ entries of $\mathrm{adj}\,A$ are zero. Suppose that $\det A=0$; then the product of $A$ and $\mathrm{adj}\,A$ must be the zero matrix. Now, the rank of $A$ is exactly $n-1$, which implies that the kernel of $\mathrm{adj}\,A$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional. In other words, $\mathrm{adj}\,A$ has rank $1$. But any rank 1 matrix is of the form $u\otimes v$, making it impossible for it to have exactly $k$ zero entries.

Comment: Yes, the olympiad is over (in fact I`ve recieved this problem in the contest).